# Append a link to a div using ajax

Tags: javascript

I want to add a link to a div based on: if true, append link1, else, append link2.

I tried:

The div

```
<div class="mainDiv">
    <a id="link'.$id.'"><div id="test">testing link</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
if($.inArray(id, data) !== -1){ 
    $('.mainDiv').find('a#link'+id).attr('href','link1.php');
}else{
    $('.mainDiv').find('a#link'+id).attr('href','link2.php');
}
```

Comment: show the content of `id`

Comment: it's just a while loop that retrieve the users id's from the database

Comment: But show the content of the id attribute after the page loads.